# AWS Glue reading glue catalog table VS reading files from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am writing the AWS Glue ETL job and I have 2 options to construct the spark dataframe :

Use the AWS Glue Data Catalog as the metastore for Spark SQL

```
df = spark.sql("select name from bronze_db.table_tbl")
df.write.save("s3://silver/...")
```

another option is to read directly from s3 location like this

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("s3://bronze/table_tbl/1.parquet","s3://bronze/table_tbl/2.parquet")


df.write.save("s3://silver/...")
```

should I consider reading files directly to save cost or any limit on the number of queries (select name from bronze_db.table_tbl) or to get better read performance?

I am not sure if this query will be run on Athena to return the results

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623655/creating-glue-catalog-tables-using-crawler-and-then-reading-tables-from-glue-job but that question doesn't have any answer

Comment: Did you find out when to use glue catalog vs when to use raw source files in s3 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one file and you know the schema there is no need for a table. A table is useful when there are multiple files, you don't know the schema (e.g. the table was set up and is populated by another process), or if you are querying the data from multiple engines (Athena, EMR, Redshift Spectrum, etc.)

Think of tables as an interoperability thing. Interoperability with other processes, other engines, etc.

Comment: There are multiple files and I have to read incremental data form bronze to silver layer. for me its more intuitive to use spark sql to read the data then reading the files